# Qt C++ Создание динамических кнопок из списка и обработка их нажатий

Tags: c++, qt

Есть `QStringList`, в нём есть, к примеру, 9 элементов (вообще их может быть сколько угодно). Нужно создать динамически кнопки в зависимости от кол-ва элементов в `QStringList`. Каждая кнопка имеет имя своего элемента в `QStringList`, расположить их в layout 3x3. Далее, при нажатии на каждую кнопку обработать сигнал по-своему. Например, при нажатии на *кнопку 5* выводится строка "вы нажали кнопку 5", а по нажатию *кнопки 2* складываются 2 переменные и выводится ответ в `qDebug()`.

Собственно, одна из проблем: как прикрутить еще не созданные кнопки к слотам? Ведь заранее не знаем сколько элементов в `QStringList` а к каждой кнопке должна выполнятся своя команда. Которая потребуется.

Comment: А что мешает в коде ***после*** создания кнопки вызвать `QObject::connect`?

Comment: Всё кажется понял как можно решить данную проблему. Полазал по офф доке и нашел класс QSignalMapper можно использовать еще Лямды. Так же можно использовать  конструкцию у слота DynButton * button = (DynButton * ) sender() которая определяет объект, который вызвал сигнал и далее работать с уже с ним.